# PHP Time between two times

Tags: php, datetime, time

I'm trying to get some code to work to detect which time value pairs the current time is between.  The code I'm using is below.  However, I keep getting 'NO MATCH' even though the current time falls into one of the ranges.  Not sure where I'm going wrong.

```
//GET CURRENT TIME
$tz_object = new DateTimeZone('America/New_York');
$current_time = new DateTime();
$current_time->setTimezone($tz_object);

//SET TIME RANGE PAIRS
$time1Start = '08:00:00';
$time1End = '16:59:59';
$time2Start = '17:00:00';
$time2End = '07:59:59';

//FORMAT TIMES
$current_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $current_time);
$time1Start = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time1Start);
$time1End = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time1End);
$time2Start = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time2Start);
$time2End = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $time2End);

//TIME 1 SLOT
if ($current_time >= $time1Start && $current_time <= $time1End)
    {
        echo 'RANGE 1';
    }
//TIME 2 SLOT   
elseif ($current_time >= $time2Start && $current_time <= $time2End)
    {
        echo 'RANGE 2';
    }
else
    {
        echo 'NO MATCH';
    }
```

****UPDATE****

So it seems this starts to fail on me when I start converting with timezones.  If I pass a raw time value, it works fine.  However, as I look at this, I think I'm WAY overcomplicating what I'm trying to do.  Essentially, I just need to determine if the current time is between two values.  For my purposes, I don't care about today, tomorrow, yesterday, etc.  I just need to know if 16:42 is between 08:00 and 15:00 or between 15:01 and 07:59.  This seems simple enough to me but I just can't get the code implementation to work no matter how much I simplify it.

Comment: What's the point of `$current_time = DateTime::...`? $current_time is **ALREADY** a datetime object...

Comment: Your end time is before your start time for time 2 so that will never match.

Comment: [Works for me](http://codepad.viper-7.com/5KOLX1) (with a little bit of cleanup which should not afect results)

Comment: @JohnConde Thank you!  SO strange - I even copied and pasted your code into my page to try that and I'm still getting the same result (NO MATCH).  Bizarre - I'll keep playing.

Comment: Start by verifying that the date and time for "current_time" is what you expect it to be (`echo $current_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') `)

Comment: @JohnConde  Current Time 2014-04-22 15:17:18 so it should fall within my Range 1.  Weird.

Comment: Can you tell us for which values it works and which values it does not work? I suspect that @JohnConde's comment that `$time2End < $time2Start` is relevant. Try your code with a bunch of different values for `$current_time` and see where it fails.

Comment: OK, so this is weird.  If I manually specify the time `$current_time = '16:15:26';` `$current_time = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $current_time);` then it works no issue.

Answer (score 0):

This you can easily check instead of your code,

```
if(date('H:i:s') == $your_time){
 //your code;
}
```